# Interesting counter examples to "If a sequence tends to zero, must the series converge?"

Tags: sequences-and-series

We know that the sequence

$ 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 \cdots $

converges to zero, yet most of us have seen that the "Harmonic series"

$ \sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{n}  $

is unbounded above and does not converge

I'm looking for more interesting counterexamples other than this one in general - so other sequences that tend to zero, yet their sum are unbounded.

Comment: @TitoEliatron : Have you read more than the title of this Question?

Comment: Not really. I'll try to do it better next time. Thank's for pinted it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is any set of positive upper density, which is to say that
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|A \cap \{1, \dots, n\}|}{n} > 0,
$$
then $\sum_{a \in A} 1/a = \infty$.
This gives many examples of series which answer your question.
However, it is not a biconditional, as exemplified by e.g. the set of prime numbers as Arthur mentioned.
(There is probably some weaker asymptotic than positive upper density which guarantees divergence of the sum of reciprocals that would have the sum of reciprocals of primes as a special case, but I'm not aware of any.)

However, the set of integers lacking a $9$ in the decimal expansion (and any similar construction) *does* have convergent reciprocal sum — this is the [Kempner series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series).

Comment: "it is not a biconditional"?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull It means that the implication only goes in one direction. Positive upper density means diverging sum, but diverging sum does not necessarily mean positive upper density.

Comment: Nice, I like this new addition to my vocab. 

Could you explain how to calculate the positive upper density of the prime reciprocal set you have mentioned @Arthur?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull Are you familiar with the so-called _prime number theorem_ (there are roughly $\frac x{\ln x}$ primes below $x$, for any natural number $x$)? It shows that the primes have zero upper density.

Answer (score 1):

A close relative to the harmonic series, but a "strictly stronger" result, is $$\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac1p=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

any sequence that is larger than the harmonic series for $n$ large. For example every series of the form $\frac{1}{a_n}$ where $a_n<n$ for large $n$. Examples are $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some counterexamples I can think of. The rough rule of thumb is that any series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ where $a_n$ is bigger than $n^{-(1 + \epsilon)}$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ could potentially diverge. Of course, you have to be careful and you should use the various convergence/divergence tests to test your hypothesis. Here are some examples:

- The boring examples: $a_n = 1/\sqrt n$, $a_n = 1/ n^{1/3}$, $a_n = 1 / \log n$, $a_n = 1 / \log \log n$, etc.
- Some examples whose terms are smaller than the respective terms in the harmonic sequence: $a_n = 1/(n (\log n)^k)$ for any positive number $k$, $a_n = 1 / (n \log ^{(k)}n)$, where $\log^{(k)}$ denotes the iterated logarithm (i.e. apply it $k$ times).
- $a_n = (n\text{th prime number})^{-1}$. This series converges because we know from the prime number theorem that $a_n \sim n \log n$.
- Let $\chi(n)$ denote the expected chromatic number of the random graph $G(n, 1/2)$ (in a nutshell, this is a graph on $n$ vertices where each edge is included with probability $1/2$). Then choosing $a_n = \chi(n)^{-1}$ gives a divergent series, because we know that $\chi(n) \sim n / \log n$.

To answer your last question, actually this would yield a convergent series. As jakehuryn mentioned, this is the Kempner series. As Wikipedia writes:

> Heuristically, this series converges because most large integers contain every digit. For example, a random $100$-digit integer is very likely to contain at least one $9$, causing it to be excluded from the above sum.

Answer (score 0):

Let me atone for my sin.

Following Jorge's answer, for any $c\in (0,1)$ you have that the series with $a_n=\frac{1}{n^c}$ is divergent but the general term still converges to zero.

You can take $H\subset\Bbb (0,1)$ a $\Bbb Q$-linearly independet set with cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ (the cardinality of continuum.

Now $V:={\rm span}\,\{(1/n^c)_n:\, c\in H\}$ is a vector space of dimension $\mathfrak{c}$ such that every nonzero member is a sequence tending to zero but such that its series is divergent.

Convergence to zero of any nonzero lineaar combination of that sequebnces is trivial.

The divergence of any linear combination is tricky, but roughly speaking, if you have $$\alpha_1\frac{1}{n^{c_1}}+\ldots+\alpha_p\frac{1}{n^{c_p}}$$ with $\alpha_j \ne 0$ and $0<c_1<\ldots<c_p$, for $n$ big enough the series behaves like $\frac{1}{n^{c_1}}$ wich is divergent.